# How do I grep a number and all numbers above that number?

Tags: linux, grep

So I have a huge list of items.
I need to grep every lines containing the number: 1300 and above.
How can I do this? Will grep do this? Thanks

Comment: could you try something yourself and post what you did and the results?

Comment: _Will grep do this?_ -- Could be, could be not, can't say for sure.

Comment: `grep` searches for patterns. Expressing this in a regular expression is a bit tricky.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

While grep technically can it's probably not the best tool for the job. If the list is in a fixed format you might be better off using something like `awk`.

Sample input:

```
a b c 1100 d e f
g h i 1200 j k l
m n o 1300 p q r
s t u 1400 v w x
```

Sample code:

```
awk -F' ' '($4 >= 1300) { print $0 }' input_file
```

Sample output:

```
m n o 1300 p q r
s t u 1400 v w x
```

`awk` goes through every line, splitting it into tokens, delimited by a space (as dictated by the parameter `-F' '`, by default it already uses space but explicitly showing it here lets you change it to however your file is formatted). The logic then says for all values in field 4 that are greater or equal to 1300, print the line (`print $0`).

Comment: Note that the assignment of the field separator and the print are redundant: this solution can be written `awk '$4 >= 1300' input-file`

Comment: I explained why I explicitly set the separator. I didn't know about this shorthand method, though. Good to know.

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can do this with grep, something along the lines of:

```
$ grep -E '(1[3-9][0-9]{2}|[2-9][0-9]{3}|[1-9][0-9]{4,})'
```

Comment: This seems to go from `1300` to `99999`, will it work with larger numbers?

Comment: Yes, {4,} will match 4 or more times the previous pattern.